# Is it possible to add a phosphor effect to a terminal emulator running under X11?

Tags: linux, xorg, terminal-emulator, visual-effects

The [phosphor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phosphor) looks like a stylish thing to play with. I have seen the [phosphor](https://manpages.debian.org/stretch/xscreensaver-data-extra/phosphor.6x) screensaver for [XScreenSaver](https://www.jwz.org/xscreensaver/), which allows running an application there ([video](https://youtu.be/G6ZWTrl7pV0) available), though it is monochrome. Is there an ability to emulate the non-monochrome effect in a colored terminal emulator running under X11? With the ability to use this effect in console applications like `vim`.

The effect I would like to achieve is a smooth fading out of symbols from the screen (drawing a disappearing trace when scrolling/removing symbols/etc.) and maybe smooth fading in with configurable fading time.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Take a look at the terminal emulator called `cool-retro-term`.

Comment: @egmont, it looks like what I wanted! Though it doesn't work with `htop` well but it is not the main feature I need. Could you provide this as the answer for me to label the answer as the best one?